# Delete message that have been sent by the Discord Bot [Discord JS]

Tags: javascript, discord

I want to delete some message that my bot has send, to a text channel,  when a user writes a command. I just found info about deleting a msg after a certain time. But nothing about deleting a particular msg.

Also i must say that it will a better option to my code to delete the message with the messageID or something like that. Not the message obj.

Do you guys know a way to do that?

Comment: What are you trying to do is delete a old message, I mean any message into the channel right? As far as I know is not possible do that. You can only delete the message obj recived by the bot

Comment: I want to delete a msg that the bot has send recently. But just when a user write a command.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible